# What are some guidelines for converting patterns into closed-form equations?

Tags: closed-form

Consider the following pattern for example:

1 + b + b^2 + b^3 + ... + b^k

What guidelines exist for converting this pattern into a closed form expression?

Comment: That's the sum of a finite *geometric progression*.

Comment: By pattern do you mean the summation $$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}b^n=\frac{1-b^k}{1-b}$$.

Comment: If $b \ne 1$, it's $(1 - b^{k+1})/(1 - b)$.